# How to elegantly find multiple siblings in xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm hoping there's a better way of doing this than what I've already done.
I've got an xpath statement that like this

```
'//div[@class="findthis"]/a[1]/text()|//div[@class="findthis"]/a[2]/text()|...//div[@class="findthis"]/a[10]/text()'
```

doing it this way feels very dumb, is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the text node children of the first ten `a` elements, that would be

```
//div[@class="findthis"]/a[position() <= 10]/text()
```

(But you've accepted an answer which does something quite different to your original expression, so it's not really clear what you are looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`//div[@class="findthis"]//a//text()`

This will find all text descendands of all `a` attributes